# I am trying to send a value/text to a window which is available by Ctrl+F keyboard action on chrome browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to send a value/text in textbox which is available by Ctrl+F keyboard action on chrome browser.

driver.get("https:\google.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

```
Robot rb = new Robot();
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);    
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F);
```

The value has to go in this Find box.I am unable to inspect the element or use windowhandler method

Comment: The "find box" is an OS level dialogue, it's not something on the web page.  The real question is what are you planning to do with the thing that you find?  You can easily search for test substring in the DOM, but that in itself seems largely pointless.

Comment: I need to search an id on the page and simply take a screenshot of it.

Comment: hmm a CTRL + F would not find an element ID, it will simply find text in the page.  You can use the Actions object to trigger a moveToElement() and then take a screenshot

Comment: @Ardesco You actually don't need Actions to move to the element. You can just take a screenshot of it after you locate the element by ID.

Comment: last time I checked finding an ID in the DOM doesn't navigate you to it.  Interacting with it however will.

Comment: @Ardesco  By searching Id I meant not an element but a specific number on that page.

Comment: so it's very unclear what you actually want

Comment: I have a particular number which is present on the page, now when i do a Ctrl+F, a find box appears and I am searching that number through this Find box

Comment: What do you want to do with it once you find it? Generally, you are going about this the wrong way.  If you are using Selenium you will need to identify the element in the DOM that contains the text/value that you are looking for.  You will then need to use a locator to find this element using the WebDriver API so that you can perform further interactions on it.

Comment: For us to help you, you will need to provide us with either a link to the site you are trying to automate, or some markup showing us the HTML structure of the site in question.  It would also be useful to know what you want to do once you find the element you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inspect the find box as it is not a web page DOM part. It is a part of a browser application. If you need to enter some value in that, you can continue using Robot class or AUTO IT tool.

Comment: Tried using robot class..it is moving the active element i.e the Google search box and not the find box.

Comment: Hi Purendra, tried with AutoIT as well, it is not getting detected